# SaaS recurring billing to use with my Ruby app?

Tags: ruby, saas, recurring-billing

I'm trying to add a SaaS recurring billing solution to my app, which is written in Ruby, we use the Sinatra framework and things like Riak.

The nice to have would be:

- A RESTful API
- Ruby API
- Returns and get JSON data (since with that will be easy to integrate with Riak)
- Cheap (we are a startup, so no enterprise solutions)

So far I was looking at: http://chargify.com/

Comment: You do know that Chagrify requires you to have a merchant account.

Comment: Why would you not go with chargify?

Comment: I was just trying to know my options, I have nothing against Chargify

Comment: Other companies that offer managed recurring billing (in no particular order): Spreedly, Recurly, CheddarGetter, Braintree. Disclosure: I work for Braintree.

Comment: Braintree looks cool, I think it's between CheddarGetter and Braintree.